# What is the correct way to change the route with hyperlinks and buttons in NODEJS?

Tags: node.js, express

I need to change routes within certain pages, then I step from the backend and generate the values ​​automatically in the onclick of the buttons or in the hyperlink href ...

**NOTE:** I pass the values ​​from the backend, because I use params, among others to achieve these values.

**I am using NODEJS + EXPRESS**

```
<!-- EM CONSTRUÇÃO -->
<header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-light bg-lilas-2 fixed-top <%= informations.checking.has.ShopkeeperComparePage ? 'shadow' : null; %>">
        <div class="container-fluid d-flex justify-content-between">
            <div>
                <% if(informations.checking.has.HomePage) { %>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default bg-transparent shadow-none" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#filter"><i class="menu-options-icon text-lilas-1"></i></button>
                <% } else if(informations.checking.has.ShoppingPage) { %>
                    <button onClick="document.location.replace('/home/v1/query?Shop=<%= informations.HTTP.querys.Shop %>&PeriodOf=<%= informations.HTTP.querys.PeriodOf %>&PeriodUntil=<%= informations.HTTP.querys.PeriodUntil %>&PeriodType=<%= informations.HTTP.querys.PeriodType %>&Indicator=<%= informations.HTTP.querys.Indicator %>')" type="button" class="btn btn-lg bg-transparent shadow-none"><i class="back-arrow-icon text-lilas-1"></i></button>
                <% } else if(informations.checking.has.ShopkeeperPage) { %>
                    <button onClick="document.location.replace('/shopping/v1/query?Shop=<%= informations.HTTP.querys.Shop %>&PeriodOf=<%= informations.HTTP.querys.PeriodOf %>&PeriodUntil=<%= informations.HTTP.querys.PeriodUntil %>&PeriodType=<%= informations.HTTP.querys.PeriodType %>&Indicator=<%= informations.HTTP.querys.Indicator %>')" type="button" class="btn btn-lg bg-transparent shadow-none"><i class="back-arrow-icon text-lilas-1"></i></button>
                <% } else if(informations.checking.has.ShopkeeperDetailsPage) { %>
                    <button onClick="document.location.replace('/lojista/v1/query?Shop=<%= informations.HTTP.querys.Shop %>&PeriodOf=<%= informations.HTTP.querys.PeriodOf %>&PeriodUntil=<%= informations.HTTP.querys.PeriodUntil %>&PeriodType=<%= informations.HTTP.querys.PeriodType %>&Indicator=<%= informations.HTTP.querys.Indicator %>')" type="button" class="btn btn-lg bg-transparent shadow-none"><i class="back-arrow-icon text-lilas-1"></i></button>
                <% } else if(informations.checking.has.ShopkeeperComparePage) { %>
                    <button onClick="document.location.replace('/lojistadetalhes/v1/query?Shop=<%= informations.HTTP.querys.Shop %>&PeriodOf=<%= informations.HTTP.querys.PeriodOf %>&PeriodUntil=<%= informations.HTTP.querys.PeriodUntil %>&PeriodType=<%= informations.HTTP.querys.PeriodType %>&Indicator=<%= informations.HTTP.querys.Indicator %>')" type="button" class="btn btn-lg bg-transparent shadow-none"><i class="back-arrow-icon text-lilas-1"></i></button>
                <% } %>

            </div>
            <div class="flex-fill text-center ml-4 pl-sm-2">
                <span class="navbar-brand text-white"><%= informations.page.general.titles.navbar %></span>
            </div>
            <div>
                <% if(informations.checking.has.ShopkeeperDetailsPage) { %>
                    <button onClick="(document.getElementById('BTNSWI').getAttribute('data-indicator') === 'm²') ? document.location.replace('/<%= informations.page.general.type %>/v1/query?Shop=<%= informations.HTTP.querys.Shop %>&Storename=<%= informations.HTTP.querys.Storename %>&PeriodOf=<%= informations.HTTP.querys.PeriodOf %>&PeriodUntil=<%= informations.HTTP.querys.PeriodUntil %>&PeriodType=<%= informations.HTTP.querys.PeriodType %>&Indicator=M2') : document.location.replace('/<%= informations.page.general.type %>/v1/query?Shop=<%= informations.HTTP.querys.Shop %>&Storename=<%= informations.HTTP.querys.Storename %>&PeriodOf=<%= informations.HTTP.querys.PeriodOf %>&PeriodUntil=<%= informations.HTTP.querys.PeriodUntil %>&PeriodType=<%= informations.HTTP.querys.PeriodType %>&Indicator=ABS');" type="button" id="BTNSWI" class="btn btn-sm btn-switch-indicator shadow-none" data-toggle="button" data-indicator="<%= (informations.page.data.API.indicatorType === 'm²') ? 'abs' : 'm²' %>" aria-pressed="false" autocomplete="off">
                        <div id="teste" class="handle-switch-indicator"></div>
                    </button>
                <% } else { %>
                    <button onClick="(document.getElementById('BTNSWI').getAttribute('data-indicator') === 'm²') ? document.location.replace('/<%= informations.page.general.type %>/v1/query?Shop=<%= informations.HTTP.querys.Shop %>&PeriodOf=<%= informations.HTTP.querys.PeriodOf %>&PeriodUntil=<%= informations.HTTP.querys.PeriodUntil %>&PeriodType=<%= informations.HTTP.querys.PeriodType %>&Indicator=M2') : document.location.replace('/<%= informations.page.general.type %>/v1/query?Shop=<%= informations.HTTP.querys.Shop %>&PeriodOf=<%= informations.HTTP.querys.PeriodOf %>&PeriodUntil=<%= informations.HTTP.querys.PeriodUntil %>&PeriodType=<%= informations.HTTP.querys.PeriodType %>&Indicator=ABS');" type="button" id="BTNSWI" class="btn btn-sm btn-switch-indicator shadow-none" data-toggle="button" data-indicator="<%= (informations.page.data.API.indicatorType === 'm²') ? 'abs' : 'm²' %>" aria-pressed="false" autocomplete="off">
                        <div id="teste" class="handle-switch-indicator"></div>
                    </button>
                <% } %>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: You may want to look into using a front end framework like React or Vue. You can use a router with React to control the navigation.

Comment: @John Ottenlips, Soon I'll study the react ... But at the moment I'm studying nodejs, to learn by the way what frameworks "camouflage" .. Could you answer me the above question based on nodejs + express?